# crypto_setup: host key file not found or corrupt

Tags: ntp

I need to deploy a ntp server with key authentication.
I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 server x86_64 as ntp server and CentOS 6.7 x86_64 as client for test.

For setup my ntp server I used [this guide](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringAutokey).

But I have some issue with this setup.
After generating keys on client I can not to start ntpd process with the following error:

```
ntpd[15940]: crypto_setup: host key file ntpkey_host_myclient not found or corrupt
```

Client's ntp.conf file:

```
server myserver autokey
crypto pw clientpassword
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp
```

Client's keys directory listing:

```
drwxr-x---. 2 root ntp  4096 Aug  8 12:35 crypto
-rw-------. 1 root root   73 Apr 28 13:11 keys
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   44 Aug  8 14:21 ntpkey_host_myclient -> ntpkey_RSAhost_myclient.3648021691
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   34 Aug  8 14:20 ntpkey_iffpar_myserver -> ntpkey_iffpar_myserver.3648021197
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  367 Aug  8 14:19 ntpkey_iffpar_myserver.3648021197
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  722 Aug  8 14:21 ntpkey_RSAhost_myclient.3648021691
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   52 Apr 28 13:11 step-tickers
```

After sending the iffpar file from server to client I made symlink to this file on the client. Then I exported this parameters:

```
> ntp-keygen -q `awk '/crypto pw/ { print $3 }' </etc/ntp.conf`
Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Using host myclient group myclient
Generating RSA keys (512 bits)...
RSA 0 26 35     1 11 24                         3 1 2
Generating new host file and link
ntpkey_host_myclient->ntpkey_RSAhost_myclient.3648021691
Using host key as sign key
```

It looks like ok, but ntpd daemon on client can not to start with error above.

Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks.